# Can you use the DBFlow Android ORM with an existng Database Packaged with the app?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, dbflow

Can you use the [DbFlow ORM](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow) with an existing `SQLite` Database. That is packaged with the app and copied (from assets folder) over on initial install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add your db `foo.db` in the assets folder and set your database class `FooDatabase` as the follow:

```
@Database(name = FooDatabase.NAME, version = FooDatabase.VERSION)
public class FooDatabase {

    public static final String NAME = "foo";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;

}
```

note the name is the same without the `.db`.

Now suppose you have a table `FooTable` with a column `id` and a column `fooName`, we needs to represent that table as the follow:

```
import com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.structure.BaseModel;

@Table(databaseName = FooDatabase.NAME)
public class FooTable extends BaseModel {

    @Column @PrimaryKey(autoincrement = true) long id;
    @Column String fooName;

}
```

it is all, test it, add some values to db and log it to show:

```
List foo = new Select().from(FooTable.class).queryList()
```

Comment: I will try it. Could I also ask, Do the models needs to match the fields exactly, for example I have timestamp fields on each record, will I need to add these as columns in the model even though I do not use them in the app?

Comment: @surfer190 AFAIK you don't need, but I never have tried :)

Comment: The database that has the data is foo.db , what if i have a .sqlite2 database? can it work? - pardon me for I don't know the difference between .db and .sqlite2 :)

Comment: Not sure @BassemSamy . I guess the filename has no difference. Normally the the `.something` is only to help the OS to open the file with correctly software, in our case, it does no matter once we are opening by ourselves.